# How copy ascii characters in a way that is not malformed?

Tags: excel, sms, ascii

Sometimes when I copy some ASCII arts it gets ambiguous and malformed. For instance take a look at ASCII art below:

```
                  /   \,~~~~./   \ __      
                 ( (            ) )Oo\      
             __   \_     @ @    _/  _/       
            /oO\_____\    Y    //  /
            \_/  )   /         \  /(  \
             /  /___/_         _\/__\  \
              ' ______)       (_____  '
               '_______)  . (_______'
               '______)      (______'
             __'_____)          (_____'__
                 /    ,-------.    \
              __/    /         \    \__
             (      /           \      )
              \)   /             \   (/
               \__/               \__/
```

When I copy it in excel it gets malformed. We also want to send these ASCII arts in form of SMS. Is there a good way to preserve spaces in different platforms?

You can see another example in excel which is not formed properly:

[image]

**NB: I use Linux and have access to different Linux editors.**

Answer (score 0):

If your art is in a text file, import it into excel into a single wide column (row by row).  This should preserve the spacing between the characters (number of blanks).  To improve the picture still further, experiment with the font (proportional v.s. non-proportional) and the row height.